# Python: can I shorten this code further for checking substrings

Tags: code-golf, string, tips, python, pattern-matching

So the golf question was like this:

> You are given a number `T` and then a total of `T` number of 17-character strings. For each of the strings, output `yes` if it contains four consecutive identical characters or contains the substring `DX`, else output `no`.

The following constraints are promised for each of the 17-character strings:

1. The possible character set is `DX2AKQJT9876543`;
2. The input string is sorted in the above mentioned order, hence the number of times each character appears is exactly the size of the longest contiguous substring of the character;
3. No characters will appear more than 4 times;
4. `X` and `D` will appear no more than once each.

Test case:

```
3
X2AAKKKKQT9765433
DX22AKKQJTT884443
X2AAAKQQJT8554433
```

should have the output

```
yes
yes
no
```

---

Note:

- Output is not case sensitive, so `YeS` is also legal;
- You may assume an extra `\n` after the end of the input.

---

My attempt goes like this:
Python, probably <s>84</s> 85 Bytes

```python
import re
input()
while n:=input():print("yes"if re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n)else"no")
```

Also, I have the following alternatives for line 3, while are approximately the same length:

```python
while n:=input():print("yneos"[not re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n)::2])
while n:=input():print(["yes","no"][not re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n)])
while n:=input():print((not re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n))*"no"or"yes")
```

Is there anything I can do to make this shorter? Thanks in advance!

Source: Question made by a friend, problem ID on Luogu is `P8466`

Comment: Your code seems to give "no" on the first test case: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lco9CwIhAIDh3V9xOCnEQX6UHTQIN3WT4ODQEmEoXJ6oEUf1202od3x441rcEqiIqVZ/j0sqXbLAh/goCIOn87PtwnD8wxCTDwXB1Wbob@3ss72kq0MQ9fi8fdHPezRwE7Cds4VhgbhWCgyRcmopfdjvOKMUjIaQRuqktRCMsd8jJ9VEcN6AfgE "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Can you check this?

Comment: @xnor yeah you’re right, I forgot to add `r` before my regex string, I’ll make an edit to add it, now it would be 85 bytes

Comment: A starting point for advice here is to not use `re` here. The import and `re.search` call are overkill what you're using them for, and they take too many bytes of overhead. Checking substrings or counting characters can be done with Python built-ins.

Comment: Can `open(0)` be used to take input here? May we terminate with error?

Comment: @xnor thanks for your idea, I’m messing around with Python built-ins right now :). Also, `open(0)` is completely fine, anything is valid as long as you take inputs from `stdin` and output to `stdout`

Comment: Please cite the source of the challenge.

Comment: @JonathanAllan edited question to include source (the source is Luogu P8466, made by my friend)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 72 bytes

```python
for n in[*open(0)][1:]:print("yneos"[all(map(str.__ne__,' X '+n,n))::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc09C4MwEAbg3V8RXIytlDYfmrgJneokOAgiwcFSwV5CdPHX2xgshd5y3MN7d2ZdXhqoMHbbntoiQCO0J20GwNe4a295lxs7woLDFQY9h20/TfjdGzwv9qIUDEolEWpQdIYE4jjPSRdvmwgaUhSlq6qWWcoZpcG9IcRR9ahrIRhj1GeKsnIiOGc@47d2kcKvBV/4yTHWUopDXM@yNE35fsWd2X/9yQc)

Knocks 5 more bytes off of Jonathan Allan's answer.

Comment: Instead of using `'X '` we can use `' X '` (extra space at start), then we wouldn’t have to slice the third argument, which is -3 Bytes.

Comment: There's a much different solution that gets [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##Xc09C4MwEAbg3V8RXNRSSs2XiXQROtVJCFQIGUqx1KFJMHbw16cxWAq95biH9@7sMj@NRsxO3j/MBBwYtdwZO@j8WChZ1qq206jnPNWLGYBLJR41eN1s7g5389bz3hVmyq7ZyclS1TVUhfcs6WHTtKE6wStKMELJuYcwUHcRgjGMMYqZpu2CMEJwzMStVTiLa8kXfrKNgnO2SehVRSkl65VwZv31Jx8), if trailing whitespace is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## 82 bytes

Can probably be golfed more, but here is a first golf:

-2 bytes by changing

```
"yes"if re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n)else"no"
```

To:

```
re.search(r"(.)\1{3}|DX",n)and"yes"or"no"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Lcq9CsIwFEDhPU9RMiUgBfOjseBQ6GSnQoYOLkUDDehNuI1IUZ89BvSMHyeuaQ4gTcSc/T0GTBU64iE@EuPkOfubq6A5/qGJ6CExdPXiJrzMDCmr@Xn7kp93N9IN8AmudHULDUghUJ6zJKNo27402MN@p5WUpBuFKDScrDVGKfV72n4oYrQuIL8)

And another -1 by changing (not sure about this one, but both your 85 bytes version and this one gives an EOFError on TIO):

```
input()
while n:=input():...n
```

To:

```
n=input()
while n:...input()
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Lcq9CsIwFEDhPU9RMiUgBfOjUXAodLJTIUMHl6KBBupNuI1IUZ89BvSMHyeuaQogTcSc/T0GTBU6AicP8ZEYJ8/Jz66CY0QPiaGrFzfidWJIWc0v25f8vNuBbv47H@FGV7fQgBQC5TlLMoim6Uq9Pex3WklJ2kGIQv3ZWmOUUr@n6foiRusC8gs)

Comment: Thanks! I think EOFError is not okay (online judge says RE) so I guess my code would also be invalid :( ... However, I think using exec in a for loop would only be a +5. Sorry for not checking the online judge requirements, again thank you for your byte savings

Comment: `"yneos"[cond::2]`

Comment: @emanresuA I'm afraid that won't work with a regex-search object as `cond`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvPNjOvoLREQ5OrPCMzJ1Uhz6qgKDOvREOpMi81v1gpuihVrzg1sSg5Q6NISUNPM8aw2ri2xiVCSQeqTdPKyihW8/9/Y64II0dHbyAIDLE0NzM1MTbmcokwMgIKBXqFhFhYmJiYQNQ4egcCRSxMTYECxgA). Unless I'm doing something wrong (which is pretty likely, since I'm not too skilled with Python).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen my first “alternative” in the question is utilising exactly that, note how I used `not` to force the match object to be casted to a `bool` (`False`), and when there’s no match, the `None` gets converted to a `True` (btw this works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`) if there’s a shorter way to get it converted, then it would probably golf off another few bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 77 bytes

```python
input()
while n:='X '+input():print("yneos"[all(map(str.__ne__,n,n[3:]))::2])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc09C4MwEAbgPb9CXEyodMiXMdBB6FQnIYMgEhwEBRuDphR/fRrFUugtxz28d2c3N8yGCLt4Pxr7chCB9zBOfWTkLamj5HKqtMtoHIw3089r3HTTBJ@dhatbrlqbXuvUpKYhskVIStwi7wWocVGUoSqVZ5xRQsC9xjhQ9VBKCEopOTJFWQURjNEjc2ztkotjDXzhJ@eo8lycEnqWcc7ZfiWc2X/9yQc)**

The check for four equal characters in a row can be achieved by checking for equality between a character and the character three positions to its right. This can be applied across a string with `any(map(str.__eq__,n,n[3:])` which will yield `True` if so or `False` otherwise.

This is inverted in the code by checking that all such pairs of characters are *not* equal with `all(map(str.__ne__,n,n[3:]))` to allow the result to be used in a slice of `"yneos"` that steps by two characters. That is, `"yneos"[False::2]` is equivalent to `"yneos"[0::2]` which is `"yes"`; while `"yneos"[True::2]` is equivalent to `"yneos"[1::2]` which is `"no"`.

To check for the presence of "DX" we only need to see if the string *starts with* "DX" due to the strict ordering and the rule that states each of "D" and "X" may only appear once. Moreover this means the string cannot have a second character of "X" unless it starts with "DX", so we actually only need to check if the second character is "X". Therefore prefixing the string with "X " allows a reuse of the check for equal characters being three apart for this too, hence `n:='X '+input()`.

Comment: [Knocked 2 more bytes off with `open(0)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250833/92689)